# Blood samples in cell lysis

Tags: phylogenetics

I will be joining a team of field biologists on a trip to some uninhabited islands in the tropics. We will be collecting bird blood samples for some genetic research. We will be out there for two weeks. Will blood samples in lysis buffer last for two weeks with out refrigeration or freezing them? Or should we do our sampling closer to the day we leave so they have less time in tropical heat?

Answer (score 3):

The exact answer to this greatly depends on the lysis buffer used, what you are lysing the cells for (DNA/RNA isolation, protein analysis, etc.) and how you intend to quantify your samples.

https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/content/dam/sigma-aldrich/docs/Roche/Bulletin/1/11814389001bul.pdf

This is a link to a standard red blood cell lysis buffer and handling recommendations. Note the following:

- Lysis buffer must be stored at low temps prior to use
- Use blood stored in EDTA, citrate or heparin anticoagulants
- To obtain RNA use fresh blood only
- For best results in DNA applications, use fresh blood or blood stored for less than 3 days.

Here is another paper describing the effects on DNA/RNA extracted from blood in ranging temperatures and storage methods
https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0184692